# Почему при отправке одного буфера двум клентам(tsp сокетам) второму данные не доходят

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, сокет, unix

Пишу ws сервер, который берет поток с вебкамеры и покадрово, конвертируя в jpg, отправляет его всем подключенным клиентам. Когда клиент один, все хорошо доходит, но когда подключается второй клиент, ему не приходят данные. Почему это происходит? Для теста открываю два браузера. Продебажил, уходит столько данных, сколько нужно.

```
  SocketPair parent([](SocketPair mainProcess){
        SocketServer server("8001");
        while (1){
            SocketClient* client = server.Listen();
            char* request = client->Receive();
            WebSocketOpener::OpenWebSocketConnection(request, client->GetSocketDescriptor());

            mainProcess.SendDescriptor(client->GetSocketDescriptor());
            delete client;
        }
    });
    rlimit test;
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &test);
    test.rlim_cur = 4050;
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &test);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(CV_CAP_ANY);
    IplImage* frame= nullptr;
    std::vector<WebSocket*> Ws;
    ObjectEpoll ep;
    thread heandler([&](){
        while(1){
            int client = parent.ReceiveDescriptor();

            printf("%d \n", client);
            WebSocket* WsClient = new WebSocket(&client);
            close(client);
            Ws.push_back(WsClient);
            ep.AddDescriptor(WsClient->GetDescriptor(), EPOLLOUT, WsClient);
        }
    });
    heandler.detach();
    epoll_event events[10];
        while(1)
        {
////здесь начинаются проблемы
            int size = ep.Wait(events, 10); //достаю из epoll соккеты, готовые для записи
            frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); //беру кадр с вебки
            int j = frame->imageSize;
            auto temp = cvEncodeImage(".jpg", frame); //преобразую его в jpg
            uchar *img = temp->data.ptr; //присваиваю img указатель на буфер с данными
            int i = 0;
////в этом цикле отправляю всем клиентам, которых достал из epoll, данные 
            for (; i < size; i++){
                WebSocket* cl;
                cl = (WebSocket*)events->data.ptr;
                cl->Send(img, temp->width, BIN);
            }
            cvReleaseMat(&temp); //очищаю буфер с данными
        }
        cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
```

Comment: А это случаем не тот же код, что и в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105439/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-sockcetpair-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2 ?

Comment: @user7860670, есть фрагмент оттуда

Comment: а конструкторы там исправлены согласно правилу 3/5? а то предыдущие проблемы там так и сидят

Comment: @user7860670, да все исправлено, эта проблема тоже исправлена

Comment: Если бы предыдущая проблема была исправлена, то этот код явно не собрался бы из-за ошибки в конструкторе mainProcess.